# I accidently changed my main terminal path

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

I am new in linux and iam learning php programing for 9 month, now this time i am installing laravel thorough composer
After installing ,  terminal says laravel command not found thats why i use google for help here someone wrote there that you have to change the path of laravel then i did as they wrote there after that my terminal not work usning any comand. All comand says not found becouse when i change the but this time i use my main terminal but they suggest the acctual folder like uuid/composer/vendor but unfortunately i use my main terminal and my main user terminal path changed now i cant use it i am stuck for 3 day pls give me a good suggest  sorry for my english coz i dont know greatly english

Comment: Welcome. How did you change the Laravel path, and what did you change it to? What happens when you use the WHERE command or FIND? Also, we recognize english is not your first language, but can you please use periods to break your statement up into sentences, and perhaps break the sentences up into paragraphs? This should go a long way towards making this question more clear.

Comment: extremly sorry for my english ,    i wrote in my terminal  as same as they post,

Comment: You wrote in your terminal the same as who post? We do not know what guides or pages or questions you are referring to. There are a LOT of questions that have been posted on this site: if you are referring to a specific question on this site, please tell us which one that is and include it in your question.

Comment: extremly sorry for my english ,    i wrote in my terminal  as same as they post,  "nano ~/.bash_profile "  then pressing enter , then this profile open on neno terminal, then i copy this path from those post  and pest in terminal   "export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:"   , and save and exit,  after exit ,source ~/.bash_profile ,   i run this comand  ,

Comment: I have now asked you twice to edit your post. Please do that. You need to focus on making your post clear, complete, and accurate. Use the EDIT button immediately below the post to begin doing that.

Comment: how could i clear more specific i dont know

Comment: i open my terminal  , then i type . nano ~/.bash_profile.    after pressing  enter. i copy a path.   this path -> "export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:"  and then save and exit