# my terminal path changed by my mistake

Tags: debian, terminal

my linux debian  main terminal path has been change by mistake.  bcouse i wanna change  my laravel drectory path. so if i wanna change my directory path . i should do  cd /opt/composer/bin .  that mean  i have to open  my directory in terminal at first . but unfortunately i didnot open current directory . without opening my current directory i use all that command from laravel help post . the post was  ,,, if your laravel comand doesnt work then do this ..       nano ~/.bash_profile
And paste

export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
do source ~/.bash_profile and enjoy ;)

Important: If you want to know the difference between bash_profile and bashrc please check this link

Note: For Ubuntu 16.04 running laravel 5.1, the path is: ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin
i copy this  from the help post ...after that  in my terminal i wrote  echo $PATH  now the problem like this...
yasirarafat@onewings:~$ echo $PATH
/home/yasirarafat/.composer/vendor/bin
yasirarafat@onewings:~$ sudo nano
bash: sudo: command not found
yasirarafat@onewings:~$

All the command  just not found not found please help i am stucking in this problem for 3 days

Comment: This question seems quite close to this one:   https://superuser.com/questions/1834163/i-accidently-changed-my-main-terminal-path